# How to split comma separated single column into multiple columns in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like below

```
Id  Name   Email

1    A     email1@gmail.com

2    B     email1@gmail.com

3    C     email1@gmail.com

4    d     email2@gmail.com

5    E     email3@gmail.com

6    F     email3@gmail.com
```

i want to get the output like below:

```
Id    Name1  Name2   Name3  Email

1     A      B       C      email1@gmail.com
```

while i am trying this following query:

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name), Email
FROM table
WHERE 1
GROUP BY Email

it having the output like:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(Name)  Email

a,b,c    email1@gmail.com
```

how to get my expected output using php mysql query.

Comment: what if you have `records / rows` in `thousands`? query will take a lot of time to convert it into columns. its not a good practise.

Comment: thank you for your reply. so what can i do for this problem. can you please guide me

Comment: what is the problem ? you didn't mentioned you just asked for converting rows into columns.

Comment: actually i want my output in the above format i mentioned. but i run that query means it shows the output like all names are stored in the same column. i want to store it into separate column in single row

Comment: you mentioned `php` in your tags and question, but I do not see and `php` code here. so if you really want to use `php` you can simply run an normal `query` and then `fetch` all records and then parse them and create the data format you need in your `php` code.

Comment: As @EhsanT says, seeing as you've tagged this with PHP, just return an unaggregated data set, and handle the display logic there with a simple loop.