# How to split a single column to separate in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like below:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(Name)  Email

a,b,c               email1@gmail.com
```

My expected Output is :

```
Id    Name1  Name2   Name3  Email

1     A      B       C      email1@gmail.com
```

How to do that using mysql query.

Comment: The question how it is currently formulated is a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096679/can-mysql-split-a-column

Answer (score 0):

Below query may give idea what you are looking for --

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Name), ' ', 1) AS fname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Name),' ', 2), ' ',-1) AS mname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Name), ' ', -1) as lname , Email FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply while i am using this query i am having the output like  fname and mname and lname  all having the a,b,c . how to solve this.

Comment: for all records is it showing the same data for these coulmns ?

Comment: yes . here i attach one link this one is i expected .  How to split comma separated single column into multiple columns in php mysql see this question this one is i posted yesterday but i can't get clear answer

Comment: here is my output while i am running your query    a,b,c     a,b,c    a,b,c    email1@gmail.com

Comment: Basically your group concat query should provide the multiple rows, and then at that query should be fine, although I can see the provided question reference , you have not designed your database properly as there may be more than three or less than three no of needed coulmns. SO YOU MIGHT be NOT GOING in RIGHT DIRECTION  --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865945/how-to-split-comma-separated-single-column-into-multiple-columns-in-php-mysql